# What do the "actions" listed in some Activities do? (Smart Home API)

Tags: logitech

Some activities have an "Actions" property.  Can that be accessed through the API or are they simply placeholders for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reserved namespace for future device keys and is not yet public. We hope to expand our Smart Home Group API in late 2016 which should include this capability. Developers that have signed up for the Smart Home Group developer program will receive an email once additional functionality has gone live.